# Exclude a particular div from the selected html

Tags: jquery

I have a html which is something like this

```
<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        // Header Content Here
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        // Footer Content Here
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer-after">
        // Footer Content Here
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to take the entire html inside class "modal-content" but not the div with
class "modal-footer"

After I take the html it should look like this

```
<div class="modal-header">
    // Header Content Here
</div>
<div class="modal-footer-after">
    // Footer Content Here
</div>
```

I am trying using jquery in following way :

```
var formhtml = $(".modal-content").not(".modal-footer").html();
```

The above code is returning me the entire html including "modal-footer" . What am I missing ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.not()` doesn't do what you think it does. It removes matches from the current set.

You could clone your set and then remove your footer:

```
var formhtml = $(".modal-content").clone()

               //Find and remove your footer
               .find('.modal-footer').remove()

               //then return to last element set and get the html.
               .end().html();
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/oGeez/jw0cfg49/1/)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(function(){
    var html = '';
    $(".modal-content div").not(".modal-footer").each(function(){
        html+= $(this).html();
    })
    alert(html);
 });
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kawadkarbk31/dcgv3po6/4/)**

Comment: Your answer is working too, but this is a bit lengthier process. Please see the answer by George. It is working fine without each. Thanks for your help and I really appreciate it.

Comment: I am not sure if George method is fast or mine, but he is going through cloning, finding,removind then go to end and then get html. But as his reputation reflects he must be right or is best way.

Comment: The speed difference would not matter in a one-shot situation like the one described. Both your answers can be made faster (but again it is not that important).

Answer (score 0):

try
Use `not()` in jquery

```
$(".modal-content").children(":not('.modal-footer')").clone();
```

Comment: This will not provide the HTML string requested. Are you assuming they will append the child elements instead? That may well be an option (JSFiddle demo?)

Comment: Something like: `$('body').append('<br/>').append($(".modal-content > :not('.modal-footer')").clone());` http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/dcgv3po6/5/ (note I simplified your selectors)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Sorry for the late reaction , Thank for your valuable comment